# Django rejecting urlencoded parameters in POST request?

Tags: django, postman

Using Postman https://www.getpostman.com/ send POST requests in url encoded format. They pass when no variables included, otherwise meet with errors, for example:

- for an integer parameter: **Type error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not ‘list’**
- for a decimal parameter: **ValueError: Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple. The list or tuple should have exactly three elements.**

For a django model with variables:

```
grams = models.IntegerField(default=0)
amount_payable = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

and with CRSF off. A Post that could generate above **errors** would be:

```
POST /mypath/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 36eac051-d7e9-b106-effa-aa1fd557a42f

amount_payable=25.22&grams=450
```

In the debug pages in Django then find:

```
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x10c6d2110>  
args   ()  
name   'create'  
kwargs   {u'amount_payable': [u'25.22'], u'grams': [u'450']}
```

It all looks well formatted, is Django having problems parsing? Have tried using other Models & variable types. Is there a problem with the format/content of the POST?

View code like this:

```
def create_transaction(request):
    this_transaction = Transaction.objects.create(**request.POST)
    return HttpResponse('AOK')
```

Comment: ` {u'amount_payable': [u'25.22'], u'grams': [u'450']}` - your variables are being wrapped in lists, which is causing the error. Can you post the view code that is handling the POST request and populating the model?

Comment: def create_transaction(request):    
        this_transaction = Transaction.objects.create(**request.POST)    
        return HttpResponse('AOK')  Have added at bottom of original post where is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` is not a normal dictionary, it is actually a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object. You need to convert it to a traditional dict, before you can use it as such:

```
Transaction.objects.create(**request.POST.dict())
```

I must say, the above is not something I would put in production - there are no checks as to the contents of the dictionary - any malicious/junk can be used to create objects.

You should use forms to validate the input, and then create objects, like this:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Transaction

user_input = TransactionForm(request.POST())
if user_input.is_valid():
   user_input.save()
```

Comment: Most grateful. Django is so very powerful, but its concision can be overwhelming.